# Core-Data NSFetchedResultsController to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Here is my Datamodel:
[image: Datamodel]

I filled the Database with Data.

Now I want to display this in a tableview.
First I want to select a day with the 'days' attribute, then get its lessons.
I want to display the attributes 'end' and 'start' in the header (`-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`)

Then I want to display the lesson data in the right section. How can I do that with NSFetchedResultsController?

I've set up a basic code:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Lessons class])];

NSSortDescriptor* sortGroup = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lesson" ascending:YES];
fetch.sortDescriptors = @[sortGroup];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetch managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

NSError* error;
[controller performFetch:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    abort();
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

**UPDATE**

Here's my Code:

TableView.m (important Methods)

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        self.del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.managedObjectContext = self.del.managedObjectContext;

        NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Lessons"];

        NSString *theSelectedDay = @"Mi";

        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lessonToDay.day == %@", theSelectedDay];
        fetch.predicate = pred;
        NSSortDescriptor *sortTime = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lessonToTime.start" ascending:YES];
        //NSSortDescriptor *sortGroup = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lesson" ascending:YES];
        fetch.sortDescriptors = @[sortTime];

        self.controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetch
                                                              managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                sectionNameKeyPath:@"lessonToTime.start"
                                                                         cacheName:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    // Configure the cell...
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    Lessons *lesson = [self.controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = lesson.lesson;


    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.controller sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    // This is the first lesson in this section:
    Lessons *lesson = [sectionInfo objects][0];

    //For testing I changed the type of 'start' and 'end' to string
    NSLog(@"start: %@",lesson.lessonToTime.start);
    NSLog(@"end: %@", lesson.lessonToTime.end );

    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",
                       lesson.lessonToTime.start,
                       lesson.lessonToTime.end];
    return title;
}
```

**RESULT:**
[image: Result]

Comment: Generally, you use the `sectionNameKeyPath:` parameter to group the table view into sections. But your requirements are not clear: What if  lesson A is from 9-11, lesson B from 9-10, and lesson C fom 10-11? How should these be grouped, and what should the section headers be?

Comment: @MartinR The times are given. It is always like this: 9-10=>lesson A,lesson B; 10-11=>lesson C, lesson D, lesson E, lesson F ...  I hope now it's clear.

Comment: Does the "Days" entity describe a single day, e.g. Monday or Tuesday? I just wonder about the plural form.

Comment: It's a fault. It describe a single day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to add a predicate that only the lessons for the selected day are displayed:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lessonToDay.day == %@", theSelectedDay];
fetch.predicate = pred;
```

To group the table view into sections, you have to set the `sectionNameKeyPath:` parameter
of the fetched results controller, for example to `@"lessonToTime.start"`. This would group
all lessons with the same start time into one section.
(As I understand your comment, lessons with the same start time have also the same end time,
so this should be sufficient.)
The same key path must be used as first sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortTime = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lessonToTime.start" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortGroup = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lesson" ascending:YES];
fetch.sortDescriptors = @[sortTime, sortGroup];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetch
            managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
            sectionNameKeyPath:@"lessonToTime.start"
            cacheName:nil];
```

To display the section header according to your needs, you have to override `titleForHeaderInSection:`:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.controller sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    // This is the first lesson in this section:
    Lesson *lesson = [sectionInfo objects][0];
    // Now build some title from lesson.lessonToTime.start and lesson.lessonToTime.end:
    NSString *title = ...;
    return title;
}
```

Comment: It isn't working properly. I've posted my Code in the UPDATE section. What have I made wrong?

Comment: You have implemented `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` completely wrong. Returning a fixed value `1` does not make any sense. The `NSFetchedResultsController` documentation contains sample code how to implement the data source methods correctly. - Perhaps read a tutorial like http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller.

Comment: I know that a fixed value like `1` is wrong. But for testing it, I've done it like this. When I implement it like this in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` `return self.controller.section.count` it has 0 sections. So the syntax for accessing the lessons is wrong. (with `NSFetchedResultsController`)

Comment: There are more errors, e.g. you do not call `performFetch`. And if you need automatic updates of the table view for inserted/deleted/modified objects, you have to set the FRC delegate and implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods. - I really suggest to read some tutorials, or study working sample code.

Comment: Thanks a mill! Now it's working. I only forgot the `performFetch` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two View Controllers:

- `DaysViewController` - here you show all days. When user selects the cell you get the day associated with the cell and pass it to the second View Controller,
- `LessonsViewController` - here you use the passed object when building your `NSFetchRequest`'s `predicate`

**UPDATE:** my answer isn't correct anymore, because the problem's description have changed.

Comment: THX for your answer. I've edited my question, added the Storyboard. At the top the user can select a day.